# How to find the table row number using Selenium Webdriver Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, webdriver

I have a table with multiple rows and multiple columns.

The HTML codes look like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
    <div id="ScheduleTable-01" class="widget Scheduletable suppress-errors Schedule-grid" data-widget="ScheduleTable">
    <div class="grid-wrapper">
    <table class="nostyles weekmode hourstype fullmonth" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr id="20631697" class="Schedule-row row0 20631697 key_AuthoriserId-1077_JobId-402704200_TaskId-CON_TsCode-35" data-row-index="0" data-job="402121200,Job XXX">
    <tr id="-499545938" class="Schedule-row row1 -499545938 key_AuthoriserId-1077_JobId-A01200131S_TaskId-CON_TsCode-35" data-row-index="1" data-job="A01763431 Job YYY">
    <tr id="-985929934" class="Schedule-row row2 -985929934 key_AuthoriserId-1277_JobId-I02010171S_TaskId-INT_TsCode-30" data-row-index="2" data-job="I02872371 S,Job ZZZ">
```

Because it is a dynamic webpage, every time the page loads, *Job YYY* will be placed in different row index. Thus, I want to know in which row of the table *Job YYY* is located. 
I can see that each row is marked with `data-row-index`,  that is what I want to get.

I am thinking about this Selenium code

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
WebElement mainTable = driver.findElement(By.id("ScheduleTable-01"));
//I am not sure about this part below; findElements By ???
List<WebElement> tableRows = mainTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```

In this case, how can I find the row number? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily use `getAttribute()` See the [api doc](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29). `getAtribute()` allows you to get `atribute` value of any `html` tag

```
//since you know the job
String job = "A01763431 Job YYY";

String dataRowIndex = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-job='" + job + "']")).getAttribute("data-row-index");

System.out.println(dataRowIndex);
```

> print

1

**Edit**

Ok, there could be couple of things impacting this.

The element is inside an `iframe`
    if so, then use

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("css for iframe")));
```

You are looking for the element too fast. Use explicit wait.

```
String job = "A01763431 Job YYY";
By selector = By.cssSelector("#ScheduleTable-01 tr[data-job='" + job + "']");
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(selector));
String dataindex = element.getAttribute("data-row-index");
```

More than one elements are being returned by the *selector* provided

```
String job = "A01763431 Job YYY";
By selector = By.cssSelector("[data-job='" + job + "']");

List<WebElement> elements = new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(selector));
int size = elements.size();
System.out.println(size);
```

See how many was returned

Comment: Thanks @Saifur.  I tried it but it returns error `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element`.  Seems the `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-job='" + job + "']"));` cannot find the element.  If I change to `driver.findElement(By.id("20631697"));`, then it can find it, but I can't depend on the ID.

Comment: Try this `//since you know the job
String job = "A01763431 Job YYY";

String dataRowIndex = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ScheduleTable-01 tr[data-job='" + job + "']")).getAttribute("data-row-index");

System.out.println(dataRowIndex);`

Comment: @keylogger U can also use xpath as `//tr[contains(@data-job,'"+job+"')]` and then use `getAttribute` to fetch dataRowIndex.

Comment: @Saifur I still get `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element`   @Vivek Singh  I get `org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //tr[contains(@data-job,'A01763431 Job YYY')]) because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//tr[contains(@data-job,'A01763431 Job YYY')])' is not a valid XPath expression.`

Comment: You have an odd ")" in the end of xpath

Comment: Thanks @Nguyen.   `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[contains(@data-job,'"+job+"')]")); `  also returns `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element`

Answer (score 1):

I tried this one here and it solves the problem.

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
    String job = "YYY";
    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[contains(@data-job,'"+job+"')]")); 
    String dataRowIndex = table.getAttribute("data-row-index");
    System.out.println(dataRowIndex);
```

Basically I just take a part of the job ID (*YYY* instead of the full name), and use contains() in the xpath.

@Vivek @Saifur Thanks a lot for the suggestions.